Does XeTeX insert intercharacter tokens recursively?
I was playing around with XeTeX's intercharacter tokens mechanism and wrote
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1
\XeTeXinterchartoks0 0={b}
ac
\bye

expecting to get "abc" but instead got
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
<XeTeXinterchartoks> b
                      
<to be read again> 
                   c

Is this what's going on here?

XeTeX sees ac and inserts b in between to get abc.
It then sees ab and inserts b in between to get abbc.
etc.

I tried looking in "3.1 Character classes" of the XeTeX reference guide and "2.3.5.1 Character classes" of The XeTeX Companion but couldn't find any explicit description of this behaviour.

I'm not sure whether “recursive” applies. Anyway, what happens is that XeTeX keeps track of the \XeTeXcharclass of the last encountered character. If the next token is a character, XeTeX compares its \XeTeXcharclass with the stored value and, if the combination corresponds to a nonempty \XeTeXinterchartoks pair, it inserts the tokens and restarts from the next token.
With your ac it happens that after processing a the current \XeTeXcharclass is 0. Since c belongs to the same class, XeTeX inserts b and restarts from it. The current charclass is 0 (from b) and the next one is 0 as well (from c that has been examined but not yet processed). Then b is inserted… Infinite loop.
And indeed, the error message ends with
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
<XeTeXinterchartoks> b
                      
<to be read again> 
                   c

showing that c has always been sitting there waiting to be processed.
From one point of view, the mechanism is similar to the space factor. After processing a character, TeX keeps track of the space factor, but it doesn't remember what character caused a value to be set. Similarly here: the a token is already gone and only its character class is available for examination.
At this point XeTeX sees a character (namely c) and sets it aside (to be read again). Now the process is similar to pretending that in between the characters a macro appears, with replacement text the interchars tokens corresponding to the combination “current character class” (determined by the already gone a) and “next character class” (determined by c, to be read again). The replacement text in this case is b and this is the new starting point, because TeX never skips tokens unless in the middle of conditional text.
Now b is simply a character, so it's passed down for typesetting and its character class is remembered. The next token is the still awaiting c. The risk of Turing-complete languages is that they allow infinite loops.

It seems strange that after examining a and c and deciding to insert b in between, XeTeX continues processing at b, not at a or c. If processing continued at a, there would be opportunities to insert any further intercharacter tokens needed on both sides of b (instead of only on the right); if processing continued at c, there would overall only be one round of insertion of intercharacter tokens, which also seems like a reasonable design. Continuing processing at b seems like a strange middle ground.

@rabbitgrowth The a token is already gone; only its character class is available. I added a few more remarks.
